# Is there a way to get the line of MySQL code that caused a SQLEXCEPTION in my stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I use this code in my stored procedure to get info on a SQLEXCEPTION:

```
  DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
        GET DIAGNOSTICS condition 1
        @SQLState = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, @SQLMessage = MESSAGE_TEXT; 
        SELECT CONCAT('Database error occurred, state - ',@SQLState, '; error msg - ', @SQLMessage) INTO @errorString; 

        CALL Collectors_Errors 
        (@errorString, 
        'Collectors_UpdateGame', 
        barcodeApp, 
        usernameApp);
    END;
```

The problem with this code is even though I know what the error is, it doesn't tell me at which line it occurred. And some of my sprocs are very long.

Is there a way to determine which line number, or what the line was, that caused the exception?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [rdebug](http://common-schema.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/common_schema/doc/html/rdebug.html) tool for debugging your stored procedures. I have not used it, but I find the rest of the tools in [common_schema](http://common-schema.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/common_schema/doc/html/introduction.html) to be super helpful.

There may be an easier quick fix for finding exactly where this one error comes from, but in you are working with long stored procedures you may find rdebug to be helpful beyond this one error.